# Modifying a list iterator in Python not allowed?

Tags: python, list, iterator

Simple example:

```
myList = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
for obj in myList:
  obj += 1
print myList
```

prints

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

while:

```
myList = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
for index in range(0,len(myList)):
  myList[index] += 1
print myList
```

prints

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

**Conclusion:**

1. Lists can be modified in place using global list access Lists can
2. List items can *NOT* be modified in place using the iterator object

All example code I can find uses the global list accessors to modify the list inplace.
Is it so evil to modify a list iterator?

Comment: As-is, this code would produce a `NameError` because `a` isn't defined.

Comment: your code examples are bad. Where do the first to prints come from? Your printing 'a' which doesn't exist and there are two outputs.

Comment: [Somewhat related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1135335/increment-int-object)

Comment: Sorry guys, 'a' should obviously be 'myList'. Fixed in the post.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

in `for obj in myList:`, in every iteration, `obj` is a (shallow) copy of the element in `myList`. So the change on the `obj` does nothing to `myList`'s elements.

It's **different** with the Perl `for my $obj (@myList) {}`

Comment: Exactly, I understand that now. `obj` is not an iterator as in C++, it basically is a copy of the object, which is ignored in the next iteration. Thus, modification can only be done using global/direct list access.

Comment: @RobW, `obj` is not a copy, and this answer is misleading. obj -- like all variables in Python -- is more like a pointer in C/C++. See the edit to [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9414582/577088).

Comment: Ade YU, I gather when you say "copy" you mean "copy of the address of the element" rather than "copy of the element itself." You might clarify that.

Comment: @senderle Yes. In Python, *variables* are just references to *objects*. Only the *variables* are copied, but the *objects*. It's just like `obj = myList[index]` happened at the very beginning of each iteration. So `obj += 1` doesn't affect the `myList[index]`. Thank you. I will improve my answer statement.

Comment: might not be a shallow copy if it is a list of lists

Answer (score 7):

The reason `obj += 1` does not do what you expect is that this statement does not modify `obj` in-place. Instead, it computes the new value, and *rebinds* the variable `obj` to point to the new value. This means that the contents of the list remain unchanged.

In general it *is* possible to modify the list while iterating over it using `for obj in myList`. For example:

```
myList = [[1], [2], [3], [4], [5]]
for obj in myList:
  obj[0] += 1
print(myList)
```

This prints out:

```
[[2], [3], [4], [5], [6]]
```

The difference between this and your first example is that here, the list contains *mutable* objects, and the code modifies those objects in-place.

Note that one could also write the loop using a list comprehension:

```
myList = [val+1 for val in myList]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I already concluded that the `obj` iterator is not an iterator as in C++, and modifying the object does not change the list. What you say is that `obj` is bound again to the new object that will be lost in the next iteration. Clear!

Comment: Great answer! It's not about 'shallow copy' talked about by the accepted answer.

Answer (score 7):

I think you've misunderstood what an "iterator object" is. A `for` loop is not an iterator object. For all intents and purposes, a for loop like this:

```
myList = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
for x in myList:
    print x
```

does this (but more efficiently and less verbosely):

```
i = 0
while i < len(myList)
    x = myList[i]
    print x
    i += 1
```

So you see, any changes made to `x` are lost as soon as the next loop starts, because the value of `x` is overwritten by the value of the next item in the list.

As others have observed, it *is* possible to alter the value of a list while iterating over it. (But don't change its length! That's where you get into trouble.) One elegant way to do so is as follows:

```
for i, x in enumerate(myList):
    myList[i] = some_func(x)
```

**Update**: It's also important to understand that *no copying* goes on in a for loop. In the above example, `i` and `x` -- like all variables in Python -- are more like *pointers* in C/C++. As the for loop progresses, `obj` *points* at `myList[0]`, `myList[1]`, etc, in turn. And like a C/C++ pointer, the properties of the object pointed to are not changed when the pointer is changed. But also like a C pointer, you *can* directly modify the thing pointed at, because it's **not** a copy. In C, this is done by *dereferencing* the pointer; in Python, this is done by using a mutable object. That's why [NPE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9414474/577088)'s answer works. If `i` and `x` were even shallow copies, it wouldn't be possible to do what he does.

The reason you can't directly change `int`s the way you can change `list`s (as in NPE's answer), is that `int`s aren't mutable. Once a `5` object is created, nothing can change its value. That's why passing around a pointer to `5` is safe in Python -- no side-effects can occur, because the thing pointed to is immutable.

Comment: Obviously, `print a` should be `print myList`, I fixed this.
Thanks for the pointer to `enumerate`, very useful, avoids to maintain your own code for the list index!

Comment: To be even more pythonic & concise, you could do either `[some_func(x) for x in myList]` or `map(some_func, myList)`, although those make copies of the initial list.

Answer (score 1):

You are confused. Consider your first snippet:

```
myList = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
for obj in myList:
  obj += 1
print a
```

`obj` is not some kind of magical pointer into the list. It is a variable which holds a reference to an object which happens to also be in myList. `obj += 1` has the effect of increasing the value stored in `obj`. Your code then does nothing with that value.

To be clear: There are no copies in this code example. obj is a variable, which holds an object in the list. That is all.

Comment: If `obj` would be an iterator as in C++, then the list object would be updated. But apparently, `obj` is a copy and changes are ignored after each iteration. Apparently, Python does the latter, which is my question.

Comment: @RobW: Repeat after me: There are no copies in this code example. `obj` is a variable, which holds an object in the list. That is all.

Answer (score 0):

In the first example the integer is copied into obj which is increased by 1.
The list is not changed.

If you would use a class instance and perform operations on it, it would be changed.

Answer (score 0):

Modification in list is allowed. Your code examples arbove are pretty garbled...

```
myList = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
for index in range(0,len(myList)):
   myList[index] += 1
 print myList
```

This works.

Comment: That's indeed what I posted and does not answer anything.