# What is the equivalent of foreach php in python

Tags: php, python, loops, foreach

I have been using PHP for several years and now, I am trying to shift to a new one. I am interested of learning python.

In PHP, we use foreach something like this:

```
<?php
$var = array('John', 'Adam' , 'Ken');
foreach($var as $index => $value){
   echo $value; 
}
```

How do we integrate this code in python?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a 'foreach' function in Python 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18294534/is-there-a-foreach-function-in-python-3)

Answer (score 4):

Python doesn't have a foreach statement per se. It has for loops built into the language.

```
for element in iterable:
    operate(element)
```

If you really wanted to, you could define your own foreach function:

```
def foreach(function, iterable):
    for element in iterable:
        function(element)
```

Reference: [Is there a 'foreach' function in Python 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18294534/is-there-a-foreach-function-in-python-3)

Answer (score 2):

The equivalent of the `foreach` statement is actually the python `for` statement.

e.g.

```
>>> items = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> for i in items:
...     print(i)
...
1
2
3
4
5
```

It actually works for all [iterables](http://anandology.com/python-practice-book/iterators.html) in python, including strings.

```
>>> word = "stackoverflow"
>>> for c in word:
...     print(c)
...
s
t
a
c
k
o
v
e
r
f
l
o
w
```

However, it is worth noting that when using the for loop in this way you are not editing the iterable's values in place as they are a [shallow copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9414399/modifying-a-list-iterator-in-python-not-allowed).

```
>>> items = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> for i in items:
...     i += 1
...     print(i)
... 
2
3
4
5
6
>>> print(items)
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Instead you would have to use the iterable's index.

```
>>> items = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> for i in range(len(items)):
...     items[i] += 1
... 
>>> print(items)
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Answer (score 0):

See documentation here: https://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop

```
collection = ['John', 'Adam', 'Ken']
for x in collection:
    print collection[x]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need get also index, you can try this:

```
var = ('John', 'Adam' , 'Ken')
for index in range(len(var)):
    item = var[index]
    print(item)
```