# Bitwise operations in class inheriting int

Tags: python, int, bitwise-operators

I've inherited from int, because I wanted to implement a simple interface for bitwise operations. Due to the non mutability of int, I have to use the integer member functions like `int.__and__`, ... .

```
class Bitset(int)
    ...
    def __setitem__(self, index, value):
        if value:
            self.__ior__(1 << int(index))
        else:
            self.__iand__(~(1 << int(index)))
```

In one of my memberfunctions I want to use the `|=` and `&=` functions, but the integer has no `__ior__` and `__iand__` member functions. So my question is how can I solve this problem?.

#### Edit:

I dont want to simplify binary operations, I'd like to manipulate the bits of an integer. E.g.

```
a = Bitset(0)
a[0]
>>>0
a[0] = 1
a[0]
>>>1
```

But I didn't wan't to reimplement every integer operation, which should still work as well. If I wrap an internal integer I've got to do that. E.g

```
a = Bitset(0)
a += 1
```

should still work.

Comment: You can have the simple interface without inheriting from `int`.

Comment: See question [increment int object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1135335/increment-int-object).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`int`s aren't subscriptable as well as being immutable, so you can't write a working `__setindex__()` method. It seems like what describing is basically a mutable bit-vector class, such as [this one](http://svn.python.org/projects/python/tags/r12beta3/Demo/classes/bitvec.py) which appears to have been written by Guido. You can use the provided `__int__()` and `__long__()` methods to convert it an integer value (although I don't believe you need the latter any more).

Answer (score 1):

There is already simple interfaces for bitwise operations (see http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#summary) e.g :

```
4 >> 1
# 2
```

You don't have __ior__ and __iand__ but you do have __and__ and __or__.
But I suspect that what you want is actually __ror__ and __rand__ which implement bitwise operations. Integers do have those last magic methods. On magic methods see : http://www.rafekettler.com/magicmethods.html#numeric

See also : http://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators