# Integer object whose value can be changed after definition?

Tags: python

I need a class that is an integer whose value can be changed after the object is created. 
I need this class to define a size that is first specified in millimeters. Later when the user-interface is created, I get a factor from the device-context that converts millimeters to pixels. This factor should change the millimeter-value of my object to a pixel-value.

I tried to subclass int (see [increment int object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1135335/increment-int-object)), but int is immutable so I can't change its value.

```
class UiSize(int):
    def __new__(cls, value=0):
        i = int.__new__(cls, value)
        i._orig_value = value
        return i

    def set_px_per_mm(self, px_per_mm):
        pixel_value = int(round(self._orig_value * px_per_mm))
        print "pixel_value", pixel_value
        # how to set the new pixel_value to the object's value ?

s = UiSize(500)
s.set_px_per_mm(300.0 / 500.0)
print "1px + 500mm =", 1 + s, "px" # the result should be 301 pixels
```

The answer in [increment int object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1135335/increment-int-object) was 
to build my own class with all the int's methods. So I tried this:

```
class UiSize2(object):
    def __init__(self, value=0):
        self._int_value = int(value)

    def __add__(self, other):
        return self._int_value.__add__(other)

    def set_px_per_mm(self, px_per_mm):
        self._int_value = int(round(self._int_value * px_per_mm))

s = UiSize2(500)
s.set_px_per_mm(300.0 / 500.0)
print "500mm + 1 =", s + 1, "px"
```

I works for 's + 1', but for '1 + s' I get a TypeError:

```
>>> print "1 + 500mm =", 1 + s, "px"
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'UiSize2'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to define the `__radd__` magic method ("right add") to control behavior when your custom type is on the right hand side of an addition.  You'll need to do the same for `__rmul__`, `__rsub__`, etc. to give right-hand versions of all operations.

Answer (score 1):

Using the [magnitude package](http://juanreyero.com/open/magnitude/), you could handle unit conversion like this:

```
import magnitude
mg = magnitude.mg
new_mag = magnitude.new_mag

s = mg(500, 'mm')    # s is 500mm

# Define a pixel unit; 300 px = 500 mm
new_mag('px', mg(500.0/300.0, 'mm'))

p = mg(1, 'px')      # p is 1 px

print('500mm + 1px = {u}'.format(u = (s + p).ounit('px')))
# 500mm + 1px = 301.0000 px
print('500mm + 1px = {u}'.format(u = (s + p).ounit('mm')))    
# 500mm + 1px = 501.6667 mm
```