# Unpacking and increase the values

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am wondering if this is possible somehow. I would like to increase both values once that I unpack it, without having to create two temps variables. Is this somehow possible with multiple assignment and unpacking? I started to try out here:

```py
a, b = 1, 1                                                                                                                                                                           
for i in [1,2,3]: 
  a, b += 1, 1                                                                                                                                                                      

File "<ipython-input-2-a1e761cf8ae1>", line 2
  a, b += 1, 1
  ^
SyntaxError: illegal expression for augmented assignment
```

```py
for i in [1,2,3]: 
  a, b += (1, 1)                                                                                                                                                                    

File "<ipython-input-3-9317a6e51de4>", line 2
  a, b += (1, 1)
  ^
SyntaxError: illegal expression for augmented assignment
```

```py
for i in [1,2,3]: 
  (a, b) += (1, 1)                                                                                                                                                                  

File "<ipython-input-4-446db199ce6f>", line 2
  (a, b) += (1, 1)
   ^
SyntaxError: illegal expression for augmented assignment
```

```py
for i in [1,2,3]: 
  a += 1
```

Comment: `a, b = a + 1, b + 1`

Comment: But no it isn't. What temporary variables are being created?

Comment: Integers are not mutable so Python has to create a new value anyway.

Comment: @yatu so it is not actually (1,1) but a function which returns a tuple

Comment: Possible duplicate of [increment int object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1135335/increment-int-object)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe `map` can help you !

```
a,b =1,1
a,b = map(lambda x,y:x+y, [a,b],[1,1])
```

> map() function returns a map object of the results after applying the given function to each item of a given iterable (list, tuple etc.)

Comment: The question is tagged for python 3, not 2. Map does not produce a list

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what you want, but maybe helpful.  Numpy can easily add the values just before you unpack.

```
import numpy as np

ar = np.array([1,1])
ar +=  1
a,b = ar
```

yields:

```
(2,2)
```

Comment: I do not want to use some external lib