# change the value of a variable in memory using python

Tags: python

(In python)
I want to be able to write something like `a + b`, and so that as a result `a` has the value of the sum of `a` and `b`, also so that `id(a)` does not change (that is, change data at the address of a variable in memory rather than create a new address with the result of the sum and refer to it with `a`).

My attempt to use `+=` fails:

```py
a, b = 5, 6
start_id = id(a)
a += b
print(start_id == id(a))
# Outputs: False
```

Comment: Try: `a = a + b`

Comment: or `a += b` :-)

Comment: Try to run this:
''    a = 5
    b = 6
    d = []
    d += [id(a), id(b)]
    a += b
    d += [id(a)]
    print(d)''

Comment: I need the function result to be stored in the memory cell of variable a

Comment: but this will not happen with regular functions in python
(they put the result of the calculations in a new memory cell)

Comment: it seems to manage memory directly, python doesn't suit me,

Comment: Does this answer your question? [increment int object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1135335/increment-int-object)

Comment: in the answers to the question "[increment int object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1135335/increment-int-object)" I did not find a clear answer to my question

Answer (score 0):

In python pass reference only for objects. 
If you want do such a thing you need to create an object that represent your integer

You can also cheat a bit the system by taking the scope of the program when calling the function

```
def function(a,b, scope=locals()):
  var_name = [key for key, value in scope.items() if value == a][0]
  scope[var_name] += b


a = 4
b = 5
function(a, b)
print(a) #output 9
```

Note that here the result will be bound to the first variable with the same value of a which could be a big anoyement.

Answer (score 0):

> want to make such an addition function (example of use: "a + b"), which will modify a and not return anything (In Python)

When doing this within a function you cannot simply use `a += b` because `a` would be treated as local variable which is not defined. Therefore you need to explicitly tell that you want to use the global variable `a`:

```
def add_to_a(val):
   global a
   a += val

a = 42
b = 1
add_to_a(b)
```

Since the actual question is now why `id` changes after changing the value of `a` the answer is: Because integres are immutable in python and you have to work around that - like in the answers in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1135335/increment-int-object)