# Deriving from int and using keyword arguments in python class

Tags: python, class, python-2.7

I am trying to implement a Setting class that should hold global settings for my application. From the base class I want to derive classes that should hold the actual setting value, can be int, str and so one... This looks like:

```
class Setting:
    def __init__(self):
        pass


class SettingInt(Setting, int):
    """
    An int setting.
    """
    def __init__(self, val = 0, **kw):
        int.__init__(self, val, **kw)
        Setting.__init__(self)
```

But when the SettingInt is used as

```
i = SettingInt(0, ul = 1)
```

I get an error:

TypeError: 'ul' is an invalid keyword argument for this function

Why?

Comment: Why `int.__init__(self, val, **kw)` and not `int.__init__(self, val)`?

Comment: Neither `int` or `Setting` know what to do with a `ul` keyword argument. What's your intention (what are you trying to accomplish)?

Comment: You should really avoid subclassing built-in types like that. Why do you want to do that? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3238350/subclassing-int-in-python

Comment: Ok, thank you, I now understand the Ints are immutable. What I am trying to accomplish is to create a "setting" class that can be used to hold application global settings. These should be writeable/readable to/from file between program runs. My idea was to use a JSON object in the settings file, and if Setting was derived from Int (and other known types), the json module could pickle a global dictionary with Setting variables. I will have to think of another solution I guess.

Answer (score 2):

You can't pass `ul` as a keyword argument to `int`, because `int` doesn't accept such an argument.  You need to just call`int.__init__(self, val)`.

It's not clear what you intend the use of that argument to be, but whatever it is, you need to handle it in in your own class, not pass it on to `int`.

Also, because `int` is immutable, overriding `__init__` will not work for changing the value.  You need to override [`__new__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__).

Comment: Even if I change the line `int.__init__(self, val, **kw)` to `int.__init__(self, val)` I get the same error message.

Comment: @Robert: That's because of what I said about needing to override `__new__`.