# Inherited class of int doesn't take additional arguments

Tags: python, class, inheritance, built-in

I was trying to answer [this question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48464960/is-it-possible-to-define-an-integer-like-object-in-python-that-can-also-store-in/48465244#48465244) with an inherited class solution, but when I tested it on my IDE my solution didn't came out as I expected.  I did some search but couldn't find an answer.

Here was my proposed solution:

```
class PseudoInteger(int):
    def __init__(self, x, base=10, hid_obj=""):
        self.hidden_object = hid_obj
        super(int, PseudoInteger).__init__(x, base)


pseudo_integer = PseudoInteger('5', hid_obj="Hello World")
print(5 + pseudo_integer) # Expects "10"
print(pseudo_integer == 5) # Expects "True"
print(pseudo_integer.hidden_object) # Expects "Hello World!"
```

To my understanding this should work in theory.  But when I run it this is what I get:

> ```
>     pseudo_integer = PseudoInteger('5', hid_obj="Hello World")
> TypeError: 'hid_obj' is an invalid keyword argument for this function
> ```

I've tried adding `base=10` when initiating the instance but it still fails:

> ```
>     pseudo_integer = PseudoInteger('5', base=10, hid_obj="Hello World")
> TypeError: int() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)
> ```

I thought I had messed something up so I write my own class and inherit it, but it works fine:

```
class foo(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y=10):
        pass

class bar(foo):
    def __init__(self, x, y=10, z=""):
        self.z = z
        super(foo, bar).__init__(x, y)

foobar = bar(1, z="hello")
print(foobar.z)

# Output
# hello
```

My question is - why couldn't I inherit the built-in `int` class and add an additional argument, but it works fine when it's inherited from my `foo` class? Is it a limitation or did I mess up?

---

In addition to @Melvin's suggestion of super() not needing args in Python 3, I tried it on my custom class, it works.  But in the built-in inherited class I got another unexpected behaviour:

> ```
>     super().__init__(x, base)
> TypeError: object.__init__() takes no parameters
> ```

Built-ins are weird man.

Comment: Is this python 2 or 3? If it's 3 you don't need arg in your super().

Comment: @Melvin I'm running on Python 3.6.3. I can do `super()` without arg in my custom class *but not* in the inherited `int` class.  I get another unexpected behaviour: `TypeError: object.__init__() takes no parameters`.  This is... another question?

Comment: Well `TypeError: object.__init__() takes no parameters` just means that `int` does not take in any input arguments in its `__init__`, I've not actually inherited from `int` before, give me some time to try it out :)

Comment: The parameters you're passing to `__init__` are first passed to `__new__` and since your subclass does not override the `__new__` of the parent class, signatures mismatch. Here's a small working example: https://repl.it/repls/ClearCourageousAlbertosaurus

Comment: @Mevin That's not the issue. They can add custom parameters to their subclass.

Comment: Appreciate all the comments and answers here.  It just goes to show my google-fu is not as strong as I thought.

Comment: @MosesKoledoye woops sorry

Comment: @MosesKoledoye that's beautiful.  I looked into the dupe threads and still couldn't understand the `__new__()` usage, but your sample made it click.  Much appreciated!  Would have happily accepted it as an answer but the question was closed.

Answer (score 0):

`int` is immutable so you can't modify it after it is created, use `__new__` instead. Try this:

```
class PseudoInteger(int):
    def __new__(self, x, base=10, hid_obj=""):
        self.hidden_object = hid_obj
        super(int, PseudoInteger).__new__(x, base)
```

Possible Duplicate of: [Subclassing int in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3238350/subclassing-int-in-python)