# How to inherit class complex in python?

Tags: python

I am working on a project where I need to deal with complex numbers. I am using the predefined class complex in python. But I would like to add some more properties to the predefined implementation.

I tried to inherit the class through a custom class, like this

```
class C(complex):
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        complex.__init__(self,x,y)
```

But it shows the error

```
TypeError: object.__init__() takes exactly one argument (the instance to initialize)
```

Can anyone suggest the proper way to inherit from class complex in python? Thanks!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Subclassing int in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3238350/subclassing-int-in-python) It is basically the same, even though the built-in type is int in that question.

Comment: An `__init__` which just calls the superclass might as well not be there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to initialize `complex` using `super()` which doesn't take any additional arguments, like this:

```
class C(complex):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        super().__init__()
```

Edit:

Or simply

```
class C(complex):
    '''No need of defining any constructors'''
    ...
    def someOtherMethod(*args,**kargs):
        pass
```

Ie. to inherit built in classes one need not define nay constructors.

Comment: Yes you are right, no need to actually re-implement the constructor. I assumed that was wanted because of the provided example, and it is a common thing to do when subclassing.

Answer (score 2):

It might be easier, to keep the class arguments as they are:

```
class C(complex):
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        return complex.__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)

c = C()
print(c)
d = C(1, 2)
print(d)
```

Output:

```
0j
(1+2j)
```

Comment: I can't get your code to work. `object.__init__()` complains.

Comment: Ok, but your answer is now the same as the duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the super class.

```
class C(complex):
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        super(C, self).__init__()

complexNumber = C(1,2)
print(complexNumber)
# (1+2j)
```

Comment: You ignore params `x,y`, so what is the point of it?

Comment: @quamrana, as complex class receives 2 variables, x and y will automatically be treated by the constructor. Run the code and check that it works. If you wish, you can do stuff with the x and y in the C class init

Comment: I mean, there is no difference between what you have and `class C(complex): pass`.