# Shadowing Python built-in int in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to shadow Python's `int` class, but I am having trouble with `__init__`.

The following code seems to work fine:

```
import builtins


class int(int):
    """Shadow Python builtin int class."""
    def __init__(self, x, base=10, *, my_attr=False):
        self.my_attr = my_attr
        builtins.int.__init__(x, base)
```

But if I replace the line `builtins.int.__init__(x, base)` to either `super().__init__(x, base)`
or `builtins.int.__init__(self, x, base)` (which I think is the same as using `super()`), it doesn't work. I will get the following error:

```
a = int(5)

TypeError: object.__init__() takes exactly one argument (the instance to initialize)
```

I also tried `super().__init__()` (and `builtins.int.__init__()`) and they both would work as well. I am a bit confused because the `int` class in `builtins.py` is defined as (according to PyCharm):

```
def __init__(self, x, base=10): # known special case of int.__init__
```

which takes at least one argument `x`.

Can someone explain the inheritance in this case?

Comment: ``int`` is an immutable type. It is not initialised, only created via ``__new__``.

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3238350/2988730?

Comment: @MadPhysicist @MisterMiyagi But the code using `__init__` does work. How come? If I use `__new__`, can I introduce new attributes like `my_attr` in the code above?

Comment: @vanbastelaer. You can call `__init__` all you want. It won't do anything. The second dupe works just fine too.

Comment: @MadPhysicist But I was able to access `a.my_attr` and I can do integer operations like `a - b` (`b = int(4)` for example).

Comment: I'm not sure how that contradicts anything in the other answers. By subclassing, you introduce a `__dict__` attribute (which you could suppress by adding `__slots__`).