# Incrementing an instance of int's subclass in it's own method?

Tags: python, class, immutability, increment, addition

I've inherited a class from `int` and I'm trying to create a method that increases my instance's value inside the method:

```
class MyInt(int):
    def my_method(self, value):
        #do_stuff()
        self += value
```

I know you can't set self to anything else inside a method, it will sure change inside the method but the actual instance wont change.
However, I don't know how can I fix this so that the actual instance would change, so is it even possible? If yes, then how?

Comment: You're trying to mutate an immutable object?

Comment: @snakesandcoffee Rather find a workaround to implement behavior similar to mutatable object...

Comment: You should probably look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33534/extending-base-classes-in-python

Comment: "I've inherited a class from `int` and..." No! Don't do that! Subclassing built-in is the wrong way of doing things most of the times. They **will** bite you in the future(and they already started as you can see). Subclassing a built-in is a great power, but with great power comes great responsibility!!!
(BTW: AFAIK you can't do what you are trying to do from python. If there is a way it will surely be nasty...)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the best thing to do would be to have MyInt not inherit from int, but rather store an int in an instance variable. So you would have a getValue() method and a setValue() method.

```
class MyInt()
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
    def getValue(self):
        return self.value
    def setValue(self, value):
        self.value = value
```

Comment: Why use getter and setters? That's the Java way of doing this.Python has `@property`s.

Comment: @property is also really useful for dynamic values :)